# how to clear unwanted td showing in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

guys i have a stupid question here.
i'm using `bootstrap.min.js` for showing a data into a table.
but it has an unwanted `td` showing at my last row. how i can clear that unwanted `td` that showing at the last row in my table?

anyone have any answer for my question? please help me for solve this.

this my code for showing the data or created the table

```js
script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('#submit-file').on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#files').parse({
   config: {
    delimiter: "",
    complete: displayHTMLTable,
   },
   before: function(file, inputElem)
   {
    //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
   },
   error: function(err, file)
   {
    //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
   },
   complete: function()
   {
    //console.log("Done with all files");
   }
  });
    });
 
 function displayHTMLTable(results){
  var table = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
  var data = results.data;
   
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   table+= "<tr>";
   var row = data[i]; 
   var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
   for(j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
    table+= "<td>";
    table+= cells[j];
    table+= "</td>";
   }
   table+= "</tr>";
  }
  table+= "</table>";
  $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
 }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="padding:5px 5px; margin-left:5px">
 <div class="well" style="width:70%">
  <div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="files">Upload File Data :</label>
     <input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".csv" required />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-file" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   
   <div id="parsed_csv_list" class="panel-body table-responsive" style="width:800px">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

and this is the unwanted `tr and td showing`
[image: The Unwanted <code>tr and td</code>]

this that i have got when i check it with inspect element
[image]

i try editing my code to this

```js
function displayHTMLTable(results){
  var table = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
  var data = results.data;

  for(i=0;i<=data.length;i++){
   if(data[i].trim().length > 1)// check added here
            { 
   table+= "<tr>";
   var row = data[i]; 
   var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
   for(j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
    table+= "<td>";
    table+= cells[j];
    table+= "</td>";
   }
   table+= "</tr>";
   }
   else {
   }
  }
  table+= "</table>";
  $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
 } 
  });
```

Comment: Please check that your uploaded CSV doesnt have extra "," at the end

Comment: is that td always appear, or just temporary?

Comment: Not really a "fix" for what is causing the problem, if it is always consistently there  I would just be lazy and inelegantly use the  css pseudo class :last-child on that  <tr> to set the display to none.

Comment: change j<cells.length into j<=cells.length

Comment: @yogendarji it not have more extra ","

Comment: @Gerard when i use `<=` it will be crash with my `row[0]` as `data[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check the number of columns you have:

```
function displayHTMLTable(results){
    var table = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    var data = results.data;

    var size = -1;
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var row = data[i];  
        var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
        if (cells.length < size) continue;
        else if (cells.length >  size) size = cells.length;
        table+= "<tr>";
        for(j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
            table+= "<td>";
            table+= cells[j];
            table+= "</td>";
        }
        table+= "</tr>";
    }
    table+= "</table>";
    $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
}
```

Comment: OMG.. i just wrong using your method 
i'm not looking the function for the `var size`

your method worked... sorry

Comment: thx''
your code work very well and that unwanted `tr and td` has gone right now

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: @MinervazMine do you have a new question?

Comment: Yeah lajos..could ou helpme?

Comment: @MinervazMine I would like to help you. Can you create a new question here on SO and send me the link?

Comment: yeah.. i will do that.

Comment: this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734966/how-to-add-only-one-column-and-thead-in-the-last-row-with-a-checkbox?noredirect=1#comment78427574_45734966

Comment: @MinervazMine thank you, I will answer the question soon.

Comment: please help me Lajos.
im stuck there T_T

Comment: @MinervazMine I have written an answer, the code is untested, if there are problems they can come from a typo or from an incompatibility with the assumed structure and the real structure.

Comment: someone has create a fiddle for me

Comment: i need your help i really don't know how to do that lajos.
this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773560/how-to-pass-an-array-from-json-stringify-into-php-function

Comment: sorry i give you wrong link @Lajos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775353/failed-inserting-json-stringify-data-into-database

Comment: @MinervazMine I have answered the first instance of the question. Critics were right that we need to avoid duplicating the questions. You can edit your original question if you need to do any changes there.

Comment: yeah lajos..
im so confuse at that time.