# how to add only one column and `thead` in the last row with a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

guy's i need your help.
i have a table that contain a `checkbox`that i have create with a data array from `csv` file.
the table look like this picture
[image]

the `id's` of the checkbox is

1. the number 1 checkbox has `id's mycheckbox1`
2. the number 2 checkbox has `id's mycheckbox`

the condition when the column and header created is like this.
when i click the `mycheckbox1` it will created one header and create a column for each data. and then when i click `mycheckbox` it just create a column (in a row of the `mycheckbox` place) and the header (in the 1st row) .

the data i want to pass into the column is `Tilting` when checked and when it was unchecked the data is `Borongan`. and i want to create the header and the column just one time only.

i have try make a code but it wont work T_T
someone please help me

Im just create a fiddle for this
this is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/minervaz/qz8tm1yb/

i add one more code for where that data come from

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('#submit-file').on("click",function(e){
  if ($('#files').val()== "")
  {
   alert("Anda Harus Memasukkan File Terlebih Dahulu");
  }
  else{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#files').parse({
   config: {
    delimiter: "",
    skipEmptyLines: false,
    complete: displayHTMLTable,
   },
   before: function(file, inputElem)
   {
    //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
   },
   error: function(err, file)
   {
    //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
   },
   complete: function()
   {
    //console.log("Done with all files");
   }
  });
  }
    });
 
 function displayHTMLTable(results) {
    var table = "<table class='table table-bordered' width='90%'>";
    var data = results.data;
    var size = -1;
 var check = 7;
    var header = "<thead><tr>";
    header+= "<th width='120'>Kode Material</th>";
    header+= "<th width='140'>Storage Location</th>";
    header+= "<th width='130'>Movement Type</th>";
    header+= "<th width='130'>Id Indentifier</th>";
    header+= "<th width='120'>Date Input</th>";
    header+= "<th width='80'>Netto</th>";
    header+= "<th width='50'>Unit</th>"; 
 header+= "<th width='80'>Payroll</th>"; 
    header+= "<th><input type='checkbox' id='mycheckbox1' name='mycheckbox1' ></th>";
    header+= "</tr></thead>";
    table += header;
    table+="<tbody>";
    for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        var row = data[i];
        var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
        if (cells.length < size) continue;
        else if (cells.length > size) size = cells.length;
  if (cells.length > check){
   alert('Data Yang Anda Masukkan Salah');
  }
  else{
        for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
  var a = 1.000;
       var b = 10.000;
       var c = 20.000;
       var d = 45.000;

       var callback1 = '10.000';
       var callback2 = '20.000';
       var callback3 = '37.500';
       var callback4 = '45.000';
       table += "<td>";
        table += cells[j];
        table += "</td>";
  }
  if (cells[5]> a && cells[5] <b){
   table += "<td>"+ callback1 +"</td>"
  }
  else if (cells[5]> b && cells[5] <c){
   table += "<td>"+ callback2 +"</td>"
  }
  else if (cells[5]> c && cells[5] <d){
   table += "<td>"+ callback3 +"</td>"
  }
  table += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='mycheckbox' name='mycheckbox'></td>"
        table += "</tr>";  
  }
    }
    table+="</tbody>";
    table += "</table>";
    $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
 
}   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.3.5/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:5px 5px; margin-left:5px">
 <div class="well" style="width:70%">
  <div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="files">Upload File Data :</label>
     <input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".csv" required />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-file" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="row" style="width:90%">
   <form action="" id="form_data" name="form_data" method="post">
   <div id="parsed_csv_list" class="panel-body table-responsive" style="width:90%">
   </div>
            </form>
  </div>
```

i have edited my code into all of my code for creating the table.
and then i will give the `csv` data here too.
you can download in here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_zAPPvH-idZZkxSRDI4NGNHOHc/view

Comment: maybe this is the problem `$(':mycheckbox')`, also keep in mind that `id` should only be assigned to 1 element at any time

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen what's problem? I must make call it as `$('#mycheckbox')` ?

Comment: Yes you must call it with an `#` not a `:`

Comment: i've try that.. but not going well. no eror callback i got. and not created a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are at least two data rows, then your HTML is invalid, since you use the very same `id` for the checkboxes of each data row. You will need to either use separate `id`s for the different rows, or modify the `id` of the data rows to `class`. Let's handle the separate cases separately:

```
$('#mycheckbox1').click(function(event) {
    $("tr.header-row").append("<td>some content</td>");
    $("tr.data-row").each(function() {
        $(this).append("<td>some other content</td>");
    });
});
```

This is how the very first `checkbox` should work. The other `checkbox`es should work like this:

```
$(document).on(".mycheckbox", "click", function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr.data-row");
    var sib = currentRow.siblings("tr.data-row");
    sib.each(function() {
        $(this).prop("colspan", $(this).prop("colspan") + 1);
    });
    $("tr.header-row").append("<td><thead>some content</thead></td>");
    currentRow.append("<td>Some other content</td>");
});
```

This code is untested, if there is anything wrong with it, please, let me know and/or create a JSFiddle so we can reproduce the issue.

EDIT:

The problem is solved.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="padding:5px 5px; margin-left:5px">
    <div class="well" style="width:70%">
        <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="files">Upload File Data :</label>
              <input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".csv" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" id="submit-file" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
             </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div id="parsed_csv_list" class="panel-body table-responsive" style="width:800px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit-file').on("click",function(e){
        if ($('#files').val()== "")
        {
            alert("Anda Harus Memasukkan File Terlebih Dahulu");
        }
        else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#files').parse({
            config: {
                delimiter: "",
                skipEmptyLines: false,
                complete: displayHTMLTable,
            },
            before: function(file, inputElem)
            {
                //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
            },
            error: function(err, file)
            {
                //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                //console.log("Done with all files");
            }
        });
        }
    });

    function displayHTMLTable(results) {
    var table = "<table class='table table-bordered' width='90%'>";
    var data = results.data;
    var size = -1;
    var check1 = 5;
    var check2 = 7;
    table +="<td width='120'>Kode Material</td>";
    table+= "<td width='140'>Storage Location</td>";
    table+= "<td width='130'>Movement Type</td>";
    table+= "<td width='130'>Id Indentifier</td>";
    table+= "<td width='120'>Date Input</td>";
    table+= "<td width='80'>Netto</td>";
    table+= "<td width='50'>Unit</td>"; 
    table+= "<td width='80'>Payroll</td>"; 
    table+= "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox1' name='checkbox1' ></td>";
    table+= "</tr>";
    table+="<tbody>";
    for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        var row = data[i];
        var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
        if (cells.length < size) continue;
        else if (cells.length > size) size = cells.length;
        if (cells.length < check1 || cells.length >check2){
            alert('Data Yang Anda Masukkan Salah');         
            return false;
        }
        else{
        for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        var a = 1.000;
        var b = 10.000;
        var c = 20.000;
        var d = 45.000;

        var callback1 = '10.000';
        var callback2 = '20.000';
        var callback3 = '37.500';
        var callback4 = '45.000';

        table += "<td>";
        table += cells[j];
        table += "</td>";
        }
        if (cells[5]> a && cells[5] <b){
            table += "<td>"+ callback1 +"</td>"
        }
        else if (cells[5]> b && cells[5] <c){
            table += "<td>"+ callback2 +"</td>"
        }
        else if (cells[5]> c && cells[5] <d){
            table += "<td>"+ callback3 +"</td>"
        }
        table += "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox2' name='checkbox2'></td>"
        table += "</tr>";  
        }
    }
    table+="</tbody>";
    table += "</table>";
    $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
      init();
}   
function init() { 
$(".checkbox1").click(function() { 
$(".table-bordered .checkbox2").prop("checked", this.checked); 

}); 
}
});
```

Comment: i have try it on my code but it not work.
this thing that make me confuse.
i'm not doing my question 1st. i try to make the `mycheckbox1` function when it checked and all `mycheckbox` has check has failed. then how i can do my question t_T

Comment: hmm i thing someone make me a fiddle for that

Comment: i have do something like this and it work
can you help me to solve something like my question?
@Lajos this is my code that i've trying https://jsfiddle.net/minervaz/L5z6yh4h/

Comment: @MinervazMine I have tried it out. If you click on the main checkbox, is everything ok? If not, then how is the expectation different from the real behavior? What should happen when you click on any other checkbox? Should a checkbox of a row show/hide a cell in that row and should the main checkbox show/hide them everywhere?

Comment: the behavior for the `checkbox clicked` like this lajos.
when the checkbox id's `mycheckbox1` has checked it will created `thead` and a column in each row last column with a value `a for thead` and `b for the tbody column`.
and then for the checkbox id's `mycheckbox` has uncheck will be change the value of the column that have create in the my checkbox row into `c`.

btw... don't try to do the behavior 1st.
try to make the checkbox `mycheckbox1` checked and all the checkbox can be checked 1st. i have try many code but wont work for that.

Comment: @MinervazMine I have solved the subproblem of updating the data checkboxes according to the main checkbox. The main problem causing you suffering was that you are using the same id of mycheckbox in multiple rows. id must be unique, if you need to have the same thing, use classes. Here is a partial solution to the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/L5z6yh4h/2/

Comment: hmmm... when the id's of the sub checkboxes must be unique. i must change my code for creating the table above?

Comment: @MinervazMine just generate class="mycheckbox" instead of id="mycheckbox" and use the class selector of ".mycheckbox" instead of the id selector of "#mycheckbox". You need to do a change, but only a small one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152196/discussion-between-minervaz-mine-and-lajos-arpad).