# How to pass an array from json stringify into php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am getting confused with this thing.

I have an array that I have built from an HTML table as a `json stringify` data.

I want to pass that array into the `php` function but with not too much success.

I tried many methods but none can't get the array of data.

This is the array of the data:

```js
// JavaScript Docume
$(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
    var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            var rows = [];
            $('.table-bordered tr:has(td)').each(function(i, n){
                var $row = $(n);
                rows.push([
                    $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(6)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(7)').text(),
                ]);
            });
            return JSON.stringify(rows);
        };
    $(function(){        
       alert(convertTableToJson ());
    });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Kode Material</th>
<th>Storage Location</th>
<th>Movement Type</th>
<th>Id Indentifier</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Date Input</th>
<th>Netto</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1" name="mycheckbox1"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>101200</td>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006540050</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>23.970</td>
<td>KG</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>101200</td>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006539985</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>42.970</td>
<td>KG</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id='display_data'>Click me </button>
```

and I try to make a code like this for passing that array into the PHP

```js
$(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
    var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            var rows = [];
            $('.table-bordered tr:has(td)').each(function(i, n){
                var $row = $(n);
                rows.push([
                    $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(6)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(7)').text(),
                ]);
            });
            $(".table-bordered").val(JSON.stringify(table_data));
        };
  
 var data = $(".table-bordered").val();
    $.ajax({
  data:data, 
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
  dataType:"html",
   success: function(data){
    alert ("Data:" + data);
   }
    });
 
});
```

but it can give the array displaying when I try to `echo` that and try to `print_r`. and this is the `php` code that I made.

```html
<?php
include('../../Connections/koneksi.php');

// reading json file
$array = json_decode( $_POST['table-bordered'] );
print_r ($array);


?>
```

Comment: @rickdenhaan like a textbox that contain the `json stringify` data?

Comment: Yeah no, that was a silly solution. Didn't make any sense when I posted it ;-)

Comment: anyone please tell me how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

`.table-bordered` is a `<table>`, you cannot use jQuery's `.val()` function on a table element.

It makes more sense to just return the JSON string from your `convertTableToJson` function (like you do in your first code example) and then call it to fill the `data` variable:

```
var data = convertTableToJson();
```

The data you post to the server needs to be an object with a known entry that you can access in PHP. Since you're already trying to access `$_POST['table-bordered']`, let's name it that:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        'table-bordered': data
    },  
    type:"POST",
    url:"../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
    dataType:"html",
        success: function(data){
            alert ("Data:" + data);
        }
});
```

Comment: No it looks like your PHP code will work fine (assuming that file you include doesn't break anything)

Comment: i try to echo that.
no data i get in that echo T_T
maybe i give it wrong syntax or something.
i just change the `print_r` to `echo ($array);` in my php file
and just get the alert data from the ajax

Comment: what do you get if you `alert(data);` just before calling `$.ajax()`?

Comment: i got `undefined`

Comment: Then you're not calling `var data = convertTableToJson();` in the correct place. Alternatively, you could call it from within `$.ajax({ data: { 'table-bordered': convertTableToJson() }, .... });`

Comment: but when i change `alert(data)` into `alert(convertTableToJson())` and change `$(".table-bordered").val(JSON.stringify(table_data));` into `      return(JSON.stringify(rows));` i can get the array of the data

Comment: Right, which is what I said in the answer's second paragraph ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152340/discussion-between-minervaz-mine-and-rickdenhaan).

Comment: i have try it
when i call `alert(data);` outside the ajax i can get the data of array.
but when call `alert(data);` inside the ajax i cant get it

Answer (score 0):

You expect a `table-bordered` key to be existent in `$_POST`, yet, it does not exist. You expect it to exist because you have a `table-bordered` inside the HTML, but that does not have a connection to what you passed. So, the first step is to make sure that this key will exist in your `$_POST`:

```
$.ajax({
    data:{"table-bordered": data},  
    type:"POST",
    url:"../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
    dataType:"html",
        success: function(data){
            alert ("Data:" + data);
        }
});
```

This way we pass `data` in the right way, but we need to make sure that `data` contains the values we need. You cannot use jQuery `.val()` for this purpose on a `table`, but I do not see the point of putting this into the HTML either. You can store it inside a variable:

```
$(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
    var rows = []; //Migrated here, as we will need it later
    var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            $('.table-bordered tr:has(td)').each(function(i, n){
                var $row = $(n);
                rows.push([
                    $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(6)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(7)').text(),
                ]);
            });
            //This line will no longer be needed
            //$(".table-bordered").val(JSON.stringify(table_data));
        };

    //Incorrect line
    //var data = $(".table-bordered").val();
    //Correct line, it is unnecessary though, as you can directly pass rows
    //as data instead, but kept this to make sure the code is close to the
    //initial version
    var data = rows;
    $.ajax({
        data:{"table-bordered": data},  
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
        dataType:"html",
            success: function(data){
                alert ("Data:" + data);
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: im still can get the array data from the ajax call to my php.

Comment: with your code above ..
the problem why the array still not passing into the php
because the ajax call are not contain the array from `rows`.
i try to give an alert in there . inside the ajax `has no array from rows` and outside the ajax `its same`

Comment: @MinervazMine data was initialized with passing rows to it, then data is passed as the value of "table-bordered". Please, check the dev tools of yourr browsers, go to the network tab and check what parameters were sent. I expect a parameter called table-bordered. Since you told me there is a problem, something went wrong somewhere, but from my perspective the problem is unclear. Can you tell me what you experience step by step? Can you create a Fiddle with your client-side?

Comment: i have solve the problem for getting the array
i think i get the data now

Comment: @MinervazMine that's great! What was the problem?

Comment: that was the just because of my xampp not up to date.
because of that i never get the data

Comment: Lajos.. can help me?
i need to know how to determine the `$_POST['data']` is empty. and still can  read as JSON.parse?  i have try use something like this.`if (empty($date_start) || empty($date_end) || empty($kode_mat) || empty($sloc) || empty($type) || empty($order))` and JSON.parse can't read them and make my data displaying

Comment: @MinervazMine you can use the empty function for that purpose, like if(empty($_POST['data'])) {/*Do Something*/}. You can use isset if you want to check it against null only.

Comment: but why when i try use `empty($_POST['somethingnull'])' or i set `empty` as `isset` i cant parse it into json parse data?

Comment: @MinervazMine How did you try to do it?